# How can i enable adobe flash player to use local cache

Tags: flash, adobe, cache

As the title says: using ubuntu 12.04LTS, how can i enable adobe flash player to use local cache?

Answer (score 1):

> #### You can edit Flash settings [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html).

[image]